# Call COM Interface it returned E_ACCESSDENIED

Tags: c++, com

I am using a com-client which running under session-1 to call a COM-Interface which is provided in a COM-Server running under session-0. It failed with E_ACCESSDENIED.
But the CoCreateInstance returned OK.

The customer is using a 64bit Windows Server 2008 R2 OS, I don't know what security configurations they modified. I am using the build-in Administrator account and disabled UAC, but the problem still happens.

Does any one have some information?

Thank you!

Comment: If `CoCreateInstance()` return S_OK, what exactly is returning `E_ACCESSDENIED` again? the *method* call? I assume it is running out-of-proc, and if so, are the security credentials for accessing created objects properly configured (and if that last sentence seemed like a foreign language, the answers is likely "no").

Comment: Thank you. It seems is related to OS Local Polices => Security Options Policy => 
1. DCOM: Machine Access Restrictions in Security Descriptor Definition Language(SDDL) synatx
2. DCOM: Machine Launch Restrictions in Security Descriptor Definition Language(SDDL) synatx

If I add the “everyone” to those policy option, the issue will disappear.

Comment: You can, if configured properly enable DCOM access for specific sids, there are boatloads of articles on it, but I warn you configuring it is a royal pain (coding self-referencing DACLS is always a sucky thing). If you can get away with what you have now, I'd do it.